# Using correct HTML5 structure in nested way, and taking correct tags within one another

Tags: html, nested, element

In building my pages generally i use below way for nesting elements with bootstrap.

```
<section class="container">
<aside class="row">
    <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></article>
    <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></article>
    <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></article>
</aside>
</section>
```

But when i buy themes from other HTML theme providers i see in their code they use it like this.

```
<section class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Please anyone can tell me what is the correct way of nesting them, which tag should come within which element, or if you can refer me to an online guide.

Comment: I don't think there's any real difference. You're just using semantic HTML tags and they're using divs. As long as your 'rows' are nested in a 'column' you should be fine.

Comment: Will it validate on W3C, i am just confuse in whether i can use `<article>` within `<aside>` or `<aside>` within `<section>`

Comment: There aren't many rules about these kinds of semantic tags. What you have validates fine at https://validator.w3.org. As you saw from your examples, you can just replace everything with <div>'s and it's the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) is a link to a discussion of semantic tags and where to use them. Misuse won't result in errors or changes to the output, but it will make your code less readable. Adding Bootstrap to the equation doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

The above code is a correct example of nesting code. In any UI, Container contains rows and columns defines under the row.